# Shall I switch from AsyncTask/http to Volley?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I read recently about Volley, it seems to be a nice framework. I want to see if it makes sense to my app to switch from `AsyncTask` to Volley.

Couple of facts:
- I use `AndroidHttpClient` as a singleton
- the requests must be sent sequentially, there's almost no parallel execution
- No caching must be used

Would Volley speed my app somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Asynctask` have following issues :

1. no orientation-change support,
2. no ability to cancel network calls,
3. as well as no easy way to make API calls in parallel.
4. With the exception of **Froyo** and **Gingerbread**, AsyncTasks (by
   default) run in a serialized fashion

And `Volley` has following adavantages over `Asynctask`

1. Easier to use than AsyncTasks
2. cleaned up the codebase and
3. a lot faster (**50% to 75% faster**)

It manages the processing and caching of network requests and it saves developers valuable time from writing the same network call/cache code again and again. And one more benefit of having less code is less number of bugs and that’s all developers want and aim for.

So `Volley` might be best option.

For more information see [Android Async HTTP Clients](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/)

Comment: 1. I dont care about orientation
2. I can easily cancel `HttpClient` calls
3. As I already posted, my app is mostly serial in terms of network calls
4. I can easily switch to `threadExecutor`, so also not an issue
.........
1. it depends
2. only if the codebase IS a mess already :)
3. WHY is it faster?

Comment: Again, I DO NOT USE CACHING in my app by design

Comment: @injecteer did you see http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: yep, I did. Some numbers and speculations only. How exactly the old and new code looked like is not shown. Anyway, I tend to think, that the *speedness* of Volley is a result of singleton usage and cache. If AsyncTask/AndroidHttpClient work in the same conditions, they should not be much slower :)

Comment: with no disrespect to `Volley` on one hand, and "don't fix the working system" on the other, I wanted to see if the Volley might help me in my context

Comment: because Volley writes every response to an in-memory byte[], instead of just passing on the Inputstream, in a lot of cases Volley is even slower / uses more memory than your custom solution.